# How to use fsck to fix usb drive?

Tags: fsck

I have usb drive, when It's mounted it show as this:

```
/dev/sdc1 on /media/kuba/JCUBIC2 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

And I have write/read errors when opening one directory, so I've unmounted it and run:

```
fsck -t ntfs /dev/sdc1
```

but got version number:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.28.2
```

How can I use fsck to fix the usb drive? I'm using Xubuntu without installed any additional packages regard fsck. Do I need to install any package to use fsck with ntfs?

Comment: On a side note: trying to fix NTFS filesystems on anything else than Windows is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Found a similar question and answer here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/86086/fsck-cant-find-fsck-ntfs

That answer is for Ubuntu, but many packages in Xubuntu is of the same name (and same function/files provided) as Ubuntu, so you can give it a try: install `ntfsprogs` and create symlinks:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ntfsfix /sbin/fsck.ntfs
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ntfsfix /sbin/fsck.ntfs-3g
```

fsck itself would call relevant programs for each filesystem type (ntfs here).

Same as the side note in the comment: personally I don't recommend fixing an NTFS partition in systems other than Windows.